# I lost a tmux window by using move-window

Tags: tmux

I sent a window to a session that did not exist yet, hoping it would create a new session:

`move-window -t <newsessionname>`

Instead, the window just disappeared. No new session, nothing.

Does anyone know where the window might be? I am guessing the processes inside it are still running, though it's hard to tell because there's tons of instances of these programs on other windows. I don't really care about recovering the lost window, as much as about gracefully exiting from those processes if possible.

Comment: Did you not receive the "Session not found" error message? That is the expected failure behaviour... What was running in that window?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You're right, that's the expected behaviour, and indeed I can reproduce it on the box where the events described happened.
I guess I should just acknowledge that it was more likely me doing something wrong than tmux acting up.